# D3D9 DrawPrimitiveUp Bug with D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN

Tags: c++, directx-9, visual-glitch

Hey guys I made a Pong game in D3D9 and have noticed that at random times after messing with certain parts of the code I get this: http://prntscr.com/16obk1 (It seems I need 10 rep points)

```
    d3ddev->SetTexture(0,0);
    d3ddev->SetFVF((D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)); 
    d3ddev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_CCW);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE );
    d3ddev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA );
    d3ddev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_FALSE );
    d3ddev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_FOGENABLE, false);

    d3ddev->DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN,360,&points[0],sizeof(points[0]));
```

I have tried everything, commented out SetRenderStates, Tried different primitive types and I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should at least share the initialization of your `points` array of vertices. There have to be at least 362 vertices in your buffer if you want to draw 360 triangles using `D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN`.